# Vb 2010 web browser object keeps throwing up a javascript alert

Tags: javascript, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, webbrowser-control

I wrote a VB 2010 Windows program for my own use which uses a webbrowser object to navigate to a list of sites I visit regularly. It has been working fine for a while, but in the past few days the web browser has been throwing up an alert when I click to go to the next site in the list:

[image]

The pages don't contain any javascript alert routines for this, and when I view the same pages in a regular browser, it doesn't do this.

Anyone have any idea what I can do to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: `have any idea what I can do to fix this`, quit using the `webbrowser` control (it's old), use a different one like [**GeckoFX**](https://code.google.com/archive/p/geckofx/downloads) same one  as Firefox... Also `don't contain any javascript alert routines for this` I beg to differ, that message you received is a java-script alert. Can you share the url to the site?

Comment: It isn't consistent. The alert will show up on a page when I try to leave it, but if I back up to the same page and try again, there's no alert. The page sources don't show any javascript alert lines. I'm trying to find a link to post.

Comment: Share the address of website and steps for reproducing the problem.